# How to insert a button inside of a jQuery Mobile Collapsible

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to insert a button inside of a jquery collapsible?

This is what I'm trying to accomplish, Im not sure if is possible and I haven't found much information about this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but the collapsible header is already considered as a button. So you will have a button within a button !?!

```
    <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h4>Heading <button href='#' id='bt01' style="width:100px;">Click</button></h4>
                    <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
            </div>
```

the position should be adjusted in CSS

Comment: You meant the one that makes the collapsible collapse and uncollapse? Because if that's the case I will need two buttons, one that collapses the button and another one for another function.

Comment: Yes, the example above include a button in the button